# Fill a form when clicked on a link - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, firebase-dynamic-links

In my flutter app I want that whenever I send a link to any user that link will open my app and **fill the form given at the page.**

For example, if this is my app:

[image: default screen]

And then I sent this link through email : https://example.com/fillMyForm?username=johndoe

Then this will open my app and fill the form, something like this:

[image: filled form]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firebase dynamic links for that. Refer this link https://medium.com/better-programming/deep-linking-in-flutter-with-firebase-dynamic-links-8a4b1981e1eb

Retrieve dynamic link in flutter like this and open form screen when link get in register listener.

```
class MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.initDynamicLinks();
  }

  initDynamicLinks(BuildContext context) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    var data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    var deepLink = data?.link;
    final queryParams = deepLink.queryParameters;
    if (queryParams.length > 0) {
      var userName = queryParams['userId'];
      openFormScreen(userName);
    }
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(onSuccess: (dynamicLink)
    async {
      var deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
      final queryParams = deepLink.queryParameters;
      if (queryParams.length > 0) {
        var userName = queryParams['userId'];
        openFormScreen(userName);
      }
      debugPrint('DynamicLinks onLink $deepLink');
    }, onError: (e) async {
      debugPrint('DynamicLinks onError $e');
    });
  }

  openFormScreen(String userName){
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("routeFormScreen", arguments: {"name": userName});
  }
}
```